# Should Foundation.Abstractions be a single module or a grouping of granular modules?

Tags: helix

I've been thinking a lot about the organization of *Foundation.Abstractions* modules (organizing base-types for IoC that Feature - and potentially Foundation - modules use), and I am a bit torn on whether *Foundation.Abstractions* should really be a single module, a grouping of separate, more granular modules, or else if it should just be core abstractions with other abstractions living in their own, separate Foundation modules.

Putting `IIndexableFoo` in the same module as `IBazWeatherServiceManager` (made up interfaces for illustration purposes, only) doesn't feel right to me, since I should be able to remove one the "Indexing" or the "Weather" feature without affecting anything else. I feel like what I should be doing is instead adding sub-modules to *Foundation.Abstractions* (i.e. using *Foundation.Abstractions* as a module group and adding a new module to that group). In this case, I might have something like *Foundation.Abstractions.Indexing* and *Foundation.Abstractions.Weather*.

In contrast, I know that the *Foundation.Abstractions* module shouldn't really be aware of what purpose it will server or by which features it will be used. As such, even though it is perfectly acceptable in Helix to group multiple modules together as a single module, I feel like breaking *Foundation.Abstractions* up the way I described in the example might actually violate the concept that Helix was aiming for. To elaborate, what I mean is that if I were to split up my *Foundation.Abstractions* module by purpose, I would inherently be making said Foundation layer module aware of the purpose.

The other option that I have is to create separate Foundation layer modules for the different abstractions, and reserve *Foundation.Abstractions* for core abstractions. In the case of the example I described above, this would likely entail having modules like the following: *Foundation.Indexing.Abstractions*, *Foundation.Weather.Abstractions*, and *Foundation.Abstractions* (or *Foundation.Core.Abstractions* if *Foundation.Core* exists and is a module group).

Can anyone help me straighten out the guidelines on when to group abstractions and which would be the better practice when following Helix?

**UPDATE:** 
In the example, above, "Weather" was actually a poor choice. The "Indexing" example illustrates the correct point, as it is for a feature that is/modifies part of the platform. I don't want to change the post yet, in case people are currently writing answers, but instead of "Weather" you can think of something like "IEventHandler" or something else that is/modifies part of the platform.

Comment: It is quite obvious that there is no reason to mix abstractions of different purpose/origin. 
Let's say, you will want to re-use the `Indexing` foundation project in another sitecore solution. In case indexing is mixed with whatever IEventHandler (etc) abstractions, you are potentially bringing redundant stuff along, which is super unnecessary and confusing. 
tldr: dont group unrelated abstractions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at what Feature/Foundation layers are defined as (I'll ignore Project for now as the question focuses on Feature/Foundation):

#### Feature

The concrete features of the solution, grouped by the business domain of the solution, not the technology.

Features should *never* depend on other features.

[Read more](http://helix.sitecore.net/principles/architecture-principles/layers.html#feature-layer)

#### Foundation

This is the foundation of your solution. Governed by the *Stable Dependencies Principle*. Note this quote from the docs:

> Typically, modules in the Foundation layer are either business-logic specific extensions on the technology frameworks used in the implementation, or shared functionality between feature modules that is abstracted out into separate frameworks.
>
> Typically, modules in the Foundation layer are conceptually abstract and do not contain presentation in the form of renderings or views - as these are to be considered concrete.

[Read more](http://helix.sitecore.net/principles/architecture-principles/layers.html#foundation-layer)

Now - how do we apply this to your question.

So a Foundation layer project, really should take some business logic or technology and provide the abstraction for one or more features to be able to use. A foundation project should *not* be a generic place to put "things" and it should still not cover multiple business or tecnology units in a single project.

When you talk about a `Foundations.Abstraction` project, this has the potential to become a dumping ground for *everything* - similar to how you never want a class called `Utilities` etc... - it is too generic and has no definition. Maintainability becomes problematic.

Really your whole Foundation layer *is* your abstraction so that the Features are not tightly coupled to the technology/frameworks that are underlying.

#### YAGNI

Another very important principle to keep in mind is: [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it) - if you *know* that the functionality you are writing needs to be used by multiple features - for example an Indexing project that abstracts the Sitecore Search API - then, yes that is a Foundation project.

But if you don't know or are not sure - then add it to your feature. There is no need to add more code to the "Stable" foundation layer than is absolutely needed. If that bit is needed by another feature later on, refactor it *then*, when it *is* needed.

#### tl;dr

The short version of that is:
* Don't add a generic project to the Foundation layer to hold *all* abstractions, your foundation layer *is* your abstraction
* Add to the Foundation layer *when* your business features require it, not before.
* The Foundation layer *still* is grouped into logical business or technology units.

`Foundation.Abstractions` - don't do it :)